# There was an error running the selected code generator in VS 2017 scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Trying to do a controller scaffolding in a new ASP.NET Core project, I get an error.

This is the exact steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Created new project > ASP.net Core web application > Web API
2. Right clicked on Controllers folder.
3. Selected Add > Controller > API controller Empty.
4. ERROR:

[image]

```
There was an error running the selected code generator:
Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
(Unable to write data to the transport connection:
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.)
```

I have the latest build of visual studio 2017 RC.

In projects csproj file I have the latest refrences:

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>

 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
```

===

I found in the event viewer that every time I try to do a scafolding, dotnet.exe is crashing in the background.

```
Fault bucket 129390288245, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
P2: 1.1.0.1179
P3: 5820b092
P4: System.Net.Sockets
P5: 4.6.24705.1
P6: 581d6231
P7: 187
P8: 17
P9: System.AggregateException
P10:

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7A90.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7B8B.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7B8C.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7BAD.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_C__Program Files_f41bf27ea39ac572c183c70b1a647b1d5fdfbab_66e69dae_3d448260

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 19b7e4e4-fb57-487d-81b6-528f04a11eb7
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: 57d54f0839232cc5a9588d9f015bb19f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wasting days on that problem, I found that "K9 internet protection application" caused the problem! once I uninstalled it, the error disappeared.

Comment: How did you discover it?

Comment: Never mind, for me reinstalling [donet core runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) solved it. I had the same code problem, but from another cause. I did as sugested in [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/342).